# List comprehensions

Tags: python

I have a `for` loop for outputting values into a list.

This is my output:

```
[[23, 34, 34] [34,21,34,56] [21,3,5,67]]
```

Below is my code that works for the above output:

```
y_train = ([[word2index[w] for w in sent[1:]] for sent in tokenized_sentences]).
```

But I would like to append a value at the end of each smaller list. How can I modify my code to handle this? My desired output should look like this:

```
[[23,34,34,**2**][34,21,34,56,**2**][21,3,5,67,**2**]]
```

so I would like to append a new value at the end of each inner list.

P.S. A normal `for` loop handling this would be good too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for x in y_train:
    x.append(element)
```

example:

```
>>> listOfLists = [[1,2], [2,3], [4,5]]
>>> for x in listOfLists:
...     x.append(2)
>>> listOfLists
[[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [4, 5, 2]]
```